# openMP for loop Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, openmp

I recently started learning openMP and I am trying to parallelize my code for convolution. Once I added #pragma to the for loop which is initializing the image array and there's no data dependency, the code broke and threw Segmentation fault (core dumped). I couldn't figure out what's wrong. Please help!

```
  // map values from original image to padded image
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)  
  for (size_t j = 0; j < n * n; j++) {
    size_t row = (j / n) + padding;
    size_t col = (j % n) + padding;
    size_t pos = (n + (padding * 2)) * row + col;
    padded_image[pos] = image[j];
  }
```

Comment: Where is `output` allocated / declared?  Adding (or removing) code, and all of a sudden things break for no apparent reason, has all the earmarks of memory corruption.

Comment: You should provide the inputs for the function.  It seems like your segfault happens because you are accessing memory which does not belong to you.

Comment: output is allocated in main() in another file. the code runs in sequential version but breaks in parallel version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computed indices does not match with the allocated size.
Indeed, the size of the allocated array `padded_image` does not depend on `n` while the accesses to the same in the targeted loop does.
Regarding the loop, the size of the array should probably be: `(n + (padding * 2)) * (n + (padding * 2))`.

Please note that `padded_image` is not deleted.
Moreover, modulus are very slow, please consider using two loops with an OpenMP clause `collapse(2)`.